# Why rAltmetric package is removed from CRAN?

Tags: r, cross-reference, ropensci

I want to fetch the altmetric score of articles using `altmetrics()` function from the R package `rAltmetric`. However, it seems that the package has been removed from CRAN. Does anyone knows the reason and suggest other ways to get altmetric information?

Thanks!

Comment: According to the [CRAN page for that package](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=rAltmetric) it was "archived on 2022-06-02 at the maintainer's request." This is not really a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. Asking for package recommendations or sources of data is considered off-topic as well.

Comment: Sure, it's not a programming question. And I get confused who do I ask? Tnx!

Comment: Contact the maintainer. You can find their e-mail address [here](https://github.com/ropensci/rAltmetric/blob/master/DESCRIPTION).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [dimensionR package by Massimo Aria](https://github.com/massimoaria/dimensionsR) - it has the "altmetric" function which gathers altmetric metadata from a DOI using Altmetric API.